# PHP when to remove session flash message

Tags: php, session, flash-message

I have my own MVC and in my `BaseController` i create simple method `flashMessage`.

```
public function flashMessage($name, $value)
{
    if(!isset($_SESSION['message'][$name])) {
        $_SESSION['message'][$name] = $value;
    }
}
```

This work good but i dont know when to destroy this session. Is good idea to put in `__destructor` `session_unset($_SESSION['message']);` ?

This work good but my message has no lifetime

```
    public function authenticate()
    {

        if(isset($_POST['submit']))
        {
            $username = $this->inputFilter($_POST['username']);
            $password = $this->inputFilter($_POST['password']);

            // check if user exist
            if(!$this->auth->autheticate($username, $password)) {
                $this->flashMessage('error', 'Error: Invalid username or password!');

                return $this->redirect('login');
            }else {
                $this->flashMessage('success', 'Success: Uspešno ste se prijavili na sistem!');
                return $this->redirect('home');
            }

         }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You remove it on read.
A simple example, by making the flash message a class.

```
class FlashMessage
{

    static function create($name, $value)
    {
        if(!isset($_SESSION['message'][$name])) {
            $_SESSION['message'][$name] = $value;
        }

    }

    static function read($name)
    {
        if(isset($_SESSION['message'][$name])) {
            $message = $_SESSION['message'][$name];
            unset($_SESSION['message'][$name]);
            return $message;
        }
        //return null, false or throw exception

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I suggest looking in already implemented flash messages algorithm.

E.g. in Yii you can set to remove flash message when it was shown:

```
$this->setFlash('type', 'message');
$this->showFlash('type');

function showFlash($type) {
    $msg = isset($_SESSION['message'][$type]) ? $_SESSION['message'][$type] : null;

    if (!is_null($msg)) {
        unset($_SESSION['message'][$type]);
    }

    return $msg;
}
```